# Consistent Choice of Root of Unity in Characteristic $p > 0$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

Let $\zeta_n$ be a primitive root of $x^n - 1$ in $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ where $p \nmid n$. I'm assuming there's no canonical choice for $\zeta_n$ like in characteristic $0$, where we can just take $e^{2\pi i /n}$. However, I'm wondering how to prove one can choose roots of unity consistently such that for $d \mid n$, we have $\zeta_n^{n/d} = \zeta_{d}$. I imagine one would have an inductive argument, where we assume we have chosen $\zeta_{d}$ for $d < n$. Then it suffices to show for $q$ prime such that $q \mid n$, we have $\zeta_n^q = \zeta_{n/q}$ since every proper divisor $d \mid n/q$ for some $q$, so $n/q = dk$ and thus $\zeta_n^{n/d} = \zeta_n^{qk} = \zeta_{n/q}^k = \zeta_{n/qk} = \zeta_d$ by the inductive hypothesis. My other idea was to first define $\zeta_q$ for all primes $q$ since they vacuously satisfy this condition, and then construct the rest of the roots but I'm not sure how this argument would work.

Comment: One way to arrive at $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ is to build it as the nested tower of finite fields of extension degrees $n!$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. That is
$$\Bbb{F}_p\subset\Bbb{F}_{p^2}\subset \Bbb{F}_{p^6}\subset\Bbb{F}_{p^{24}}\subset\cdots.$$ So you also get for example $\Bbb{F}_{p^3}$ as a subfield of $\Bbb{F}_{p^6}$ et cetera. Then you use the fact that all the multiplicative groups of the fields in the tower are cyclic. This means that you arrive at consistent choices of roots of unity of orders $$p-1\mid p^2-1\mid p^6-1\mid p^{24}-1\cdots.$$

Comment: (cont'd) By selecting a generator of the multiplicative group of the next field in the chain in such a way that its appropriate power is the generator of the preceding field. And you get the rest (consistently) in between. Remember that every non-zero element of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ is a root of unity :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to first recursively choose $\zeta_{p^{n!}-1}$ (i.e., a generator of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}}$) for each $n$.  Having chosen $\zeta_{p^{n!}-1}$, choose $\zeta_{p^{(n+1)!}-1}$ to be a primitive $(p^{(n+1)!}-1)$st root of unity such that $\zeta_{p^{(n+1)!}-1}^{(p^{(n+1)!}-1)/(p^{n!}-1)}=\zeta_{p^{n!}-1}$.  Then, for arbitrary $m$, define $\zeta_m$ to be $\zeta_{p^{n!}-1}^{(p^{n!}-1)/m}$ for any $n$ such that $m$ divides $p^{n!}-1$.  This is independent of the choice of such an $n$ since if $n<N$ then $\zeta_{(p^{N!}-1)!}^{(p^{N!}-1)/(p^{n!}-1)}=\zeta_{p^{n!}-1}$ by construction so $\zeta_{p^{N!}-1}^{(p^{N!}-1)/m}=\zeta_{p^{n!}-1}^{(p^{n!}-1)/m}$.  Similarly, if $d$ divides $m$, then for sufficiently large $n$, $\zeta_d=\zeta_{(p^{n!}-1)}^{(p^{n!}-1)/d}=(\zeta_{(p^{n!}-1)}^{(p^{n!}-1)/m})^{m/d}=\zeta_m^{m/d}$.

(The only actually relevant property of the numbers $a_n=p^{n!}-1$ used here is that they form a sequence $a_0\mid a_1\mid a_2\mid\dots$ such that any integer $m$ that is coprime to $p$ divides some $a_n$.  The point is that this gives a sequence that is cofinal in the divisibility poset for your roots of unity, so you can just go up the sequence step by step instead of trying to make a bunch of non-linearly ordered roots of unity compatible with each other.  Another approach that is useful in more general contexts where you don't necessarily have such a sequence would be to recursively choose $\zeta_{q^n}$ for each prime $q$ different from $p$, and then combine them using the Chinese remainder theorem to get $\zeta_m$ for arbitrary $m$.)

Comment: A possibility, but while increasing $n$ you need to skip multiples of $p$. Simply because there is no primitive root of unity of order $p$ in $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$. Due to $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$.

Comment: Er, right.  The idea still works but gets notationally awkward.

Comment: My feeling exactly :-)

Comment: I guess maybe the right way to do it cleanly is to use $p^{n!}-1$ instead of $n!$.